# Multi-Layer Perceptrons in EmguCV

Tags: c#, neural-network, opencv3.1, emgucv

I'm trying to implement Multi-Layer Perceptrons (MLP) neural networks using EmguCV 3.1 (a dot NET wrapper for OpenCV library) in C#(Windows Form). In order to practice with this library I decide to implement `OR` operation using MLP.

I create MLP using "Initialize" method and learn it using "Train" method as below:

```
private void Initialize()
{
    NETWORK.SetActivationFunction(
    ANN_MLP.AnnMlpActivationFunction.SigmoidSym);

    NETWORK.SetTrainMethod(ANN_MLP.AnnMlpTrainMethod.Backprop);

    Matrix<double> layers = new Matrix<double>(new Size(4, 1));
    layers[0, 0] = 2;
    layers[0, 1] = 2;
    layers[0, 2] = 2;
    layers[0, 3] = 1;
    NETWORK.SetLayerSizes(layers);
}

private void Train()
{
    // providing data for input

    Matrix<float> input = new Matrix<float>(4, 2);
    input[0, 0] = MIN_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION; input[0, 1] = MIN_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;
    input[1, 0] = MIN_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION; input[1, 1] = MAX_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;
    input[2, 0] = MAX_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION; input[2, 1] = MIN_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;
    input[3, 0] = MAX_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION; input[3, 1] = MAX_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;

    //providing data for output
    Matrix<float> output = new Matrix<float>(4, 1);
    output[0, 0] = MIN_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;
    output[1, 0] = MAX_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;
    output[2, 0] = MAX_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;
    output[3, 0] = MAX_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;


    // mixing input and output for training
    TrainData mixedData = new TrainData(
        input,
        Emgu.CV.ML.MlEnum.DataLayoutType.RowSample,
        output);

    // stop condition = 1 million iterations
    NETWORK.TermCriteria = new MCvTermCriteria(1000000);

    // training
    NETWORK.Train(mixedData);
}
```

Where `MIN_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION`, and `MAX_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION` are equal to -1.7159 and 1.7159, respectively ([according to OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/ded/group__ml.html#gade71470ec8814021728f8b31b09773b0)). After 1000000 iterations of (as you see in my code in stop condition), I test my network for prediction using Predict method as below:

```
private void Predict()
{
    Matrix<float> input = new Matrix<float>(1, 2);
    input[0, 0] = MIN_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;
    input[0, 1] = MIN_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;

    Matrix<float> output = new Matrix<float>(1, 1);

    NETWORK.Predict(input, output);
    MessageBox.Show(output[0, 0].ToString());

    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    input[0, 0] = MIN_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;
    input[0, 1] = MAX_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;

    NETWORK.Predict(input, output);
    MessageBox.Show(output[0, 0].ToString());

    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    input[0, 0] = MAX_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;
    input[0, 1] = MIN_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;

    NETWORK.Predict(input, output);
    MessageBox.Show(output[0, 0].ToString());

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////

    input[0, 0] = MAX_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;
    input[0, 1] = MAX_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION;

    NETWORK.Predict(input, output);
    MessageBox.Show(output[0, 0].ToString());
}
```

Here is a sample of what NETWORK predicts:
-0.00734469
-0.03184918
0.02080269
-0.006674092

I expect be some thing like this:
-1.7
+1.7
+1.7
+1.7

What is wrong among my codes?

Note that I also use 0, 1 for `MIN_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION` and `MAX_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION` values but I still do not any good results.

Update 1:
I edit my codes as first answer refers me (even I test my code with idea referenced in comments). Now I get `NaN` when call `predict` method.

Comment: maybe posting here will receive more feedback - http://www.emgu.com/forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to new version of EmguCV ([Emgu.CV-3.1.0-r16.12](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Version_History)) the problem was a bug in version 3.1.0 Now it is fixed in [Emgu.CV-3.1.0-r16.12](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Version_History). By downloading this version, I get correct responses from my network.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an error in the providing data for output. Use `output` array instead of `input`.

I think your output responses should be 2D-matrix (with 2 columns). The last layer should have 2 output neurons, because you have 2 classes for example `(1, 0) is class "True"` and `(0, 1) is class "False"`. Also try to change the architecture of your network. Logic operator `OR` is linearly separable i.e. it can be performed using a single perceprton.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your. Now my problem is all of outputs are NaN! How can I fix it?

Comment: Make sure to set the layer size first, then the activation function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871277/opencv-3-1-ann-predict-returns-nan. Glad to help you!

Comment: @Babak.Abad I ran your code and received NaN results too. I used the latest NuGet package EmguCV v3.1.0.1 for .NET Framework 4.5.
Also I tried to run an example from [Wiki](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/ANN_MLP_(Neural_Network)_in_CSharp) for Emgu CV 3.x but I had all NaN for `response` after call `network.Predict(...)`. It is very abnormal behaviour with `ANN_MLP` in Emgu CV, seems it is bug.
Try to rewrite your code using C++ (Open CV) or using another C# library for neural networks.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think that it is a bug. I also test different combination as you said. Do you know any library using OpenCL 1.2? I tested AforgeNet, but it is not fast for training because it is not based on GPU.

Comment: Try to see wiki page [Comparison of deep learning software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_deep_learning_software). There are some libraries for example experimental [Caffe OpenCL](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/opencl), [OpenCV with OpenCL](http://opencv.org/platforms/opencl.html) but you should write C# wrappers on it.